# How can I use regular expression with non greedy in python from right to left?

Tags: python, regex

Here is string:

```
step into
1
2
step into
3
4
step out
```

when I run:

```
r = re.compile('step into[\s\S]*?step out').search(s).group()
```

I get:

```
step into
1
2
step into
3
4
step out
```

However, I want:

```
step into
3
4
step out
```

It seems I should make non-greedy regular search from right to left to get the right result. How can I do it with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```
\bstep into(?:(?!step into).)*?\bstep out\b
```

Python script:

```
inp = """step into
1
2
step into
3
4
step out"""
matches = re.findall(r'\bstep into(?:(?!step into).)*?\bstep out\b', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['step into\n3\n4\nstep out']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\bstep into           match "step into"
(?:(?!step into).)*?  match any content, across newlines, so long as "step into"
                      is NOT encountered before seeing "step out"
\bstep out\b          match the first "step out" after "step into"
```